# Can't write to storage after some time

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a Galaxy S II GT-I9100 4.1.2 Rooted.

I have to restart my phone to be able to basically do anything involving writing to a file, such as taking a picture, browsing, copying anything through USB. I cant delete anything. Apps cant download and show pictures. But i can get messages, strange. This happens after some random time and a restart fixes it. Usually it takes like 10 mins or so. I thought it might be overheating but its fine. It has been like this since around 6 months and it was fine before and I changed nothing.